# Issue terminal commands that are piped to a shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, pipe

I have what seems to be a simple use case: I launch a script (python or bash) which runs an emulator from command prompt and then the emulator takes commands until I type ctrl-c or exit. I want to do this same thing from a shell and my code below isn't working. What I am trying to do is test automation so I want to issue commands directly to the application from command shell. In python, I have the following:

```
    import os 
    import subprocess

    command = ['/usr/local/bin/YCTV-SIM.sh', '-Latest'] #emulator for yahoo widgets
    process = subprocess.Popen( command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE )

    time.sleep(12) #wait for launch to finish
    print '/widgets 1' #first command to issue
    print '/key enter' #second command to issue

    process.wait()
```

As you can see, this is some pretty simple stuff. When 'YCTV-SIM.sh' is launched from the command shell, I am put into an input mode and my key entries are sent to the application shell (YCTV-SIM.sh reads raw input) so ideally, I would be able to pipe text directly to this application shell. So far tho, nothing happens; test outputs to the console window but the application does not respond to the commands that I attempt to issue. I am using python 2.6.3, if that matters, but Python is not required..

Language is immaterial at this point so PERL, Python, Bash, TCL... whatever you can suggest that might help.

Comment: You should not run it with `shell=True`. Then, your `print` is not going to the process stdin, but your parent process stdout.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect `stdin` of the child process and write into it. See e.g. [`subprocess.Popen.communicate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

Comment: So I tried the following:
        p2.communicate( '/widgets 1' )
        p2.communicate( '/key enter' )

This generated the following errors:
...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 701, in communicate
    return self._communicate(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1226, in _communicate
    self.stderr.close()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 17, in <module>
    p2.communicate( '/key enter' )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 690, in communicate
    self.stdin.write(input)

Comment: @MickeyKawick I don't see the actual exception text

Comment: It's hard to tell, but this looks like the error:
GLib-CRITICAL **: g_io_channel_write_chars: assertion `channel->is_writeable' failed

Comment: this is the new code:
        process.communicate( '/widgets 1' )